# Eclipse - How to give dependency between projects?

Tags: eclipse, dependencies

I have two java projects in eclipse. Second one is using first one's jar. When I try to navigate to first one's class from second one, it opens `.class` of that file. But I want to open the first one project file. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090829/how-to-reference-a-different-java-project-in-eclipse

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want to link your second project with your first project, don't add the first project in form of a JAR file to the second.

Instead open the **project properties** of the second project and select "**Java Build Path**". On the right side on the "**Projects**" tab you can add your first project as "required project on the build path".

The class files of project 1 are now added to the class path of project 2. And if you click on a class name you directly get to the source code.

Comment: I have an Eclipse project generated from an SBT project (using the plugin), which already set up the dependency; but Eclipse still cannot see ProjX from ProjY (ProjY is set up to depend on ProjX). Any ideas?

Comment: when i am deploying my project to the server it throws an exception `The import util cannot be resolved DataLayer cannot be resolved` even i also added my project in deployment assembly as well, what is still i'am doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, the JAR of the first project would appear under the "Referenced Libraries" of the second project.
Right-click on that JAR, and choose Properties -> Java Source Attachment.
Provide a variable that links to the source files of this JAR.

Alternatively, install a decompiler plugin (see [jd-eclipse](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/)) which will decompile class files when you navigate them in Eclipse, so that you can see the source.

Answer (score 0):

### Make one project in Eclipse depend on another so that the dependencies are available in the indexer

*Tested on Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers 2022-09 (4.25.0) on Linux Ubuntu 18.04.*

For C++, right-click on the project which depends on another project. Go to "Properties" --> Project References --> check the box next to the project whose files and resources you'd like to be available in the project you are editing --> click "Apply and Close".

The indexed resources in the project next to the box you just checked (`glib` in the screenshot below) are now available to the project whose properties you just edited! This means if you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> a variable which is defined in the project you are editing, your indexer will now jump to its definition even if it lies in the referenced project (`glib` in this case)!

Screenshot:

[image]

Done!

---

#### Old and wrong answer (but may be helpful for adding includes to your project)

For C++, right-click on the project which depends on another project. Go to "Properties" --> C/C++ Include Paths and Symbols --> click "Add Include Path from Workspace..." --> choose the project from your workspace which it depends on, and drill down into the folder of interest --> click "OK". Click "Apply and Close".

You've now made your project whose properties you just edited depend on the other project in such a way that the dependent project dir you just added will now be indexed!

[image]