# IntelliJ IDEA - How to give dependency between projects?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've recently moved to IDEA from Eclipse and would like to do simple task of making one project depend on another.

With Eclipse it's straight forward as mentioned in 
[Eclipse - How to give dependency between projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553677/eclipse-how-to-give-dependency-between-projects)

But since last few days; I couldn't make it work with IDEA. Their support page neither forum post has helped in resolving this issue.

Please let me how to fix this problem

Thanks & Regards,
Vikram

P.S. I did try solutions mentioned in comments as below. But it didn't to resolve issue with IDEA version 2017.1.5. Thus I feel this shouldn't be marked as duplicate. IDEA is changing each year & they might have introduced bug.

Comment: Your question [is already answered](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000448990-How-to-combine-3-maven-projects-into-single-window?page=1#community_comment_115000360310). If the project is not based on Maven, you simply use [Module Dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/working-with-module-dependencies.html) dialog and specify the dependencies manually. For the Maven projects you define modules in the root pom.xml and the dependencies between modules in the child pom.xml files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ: Working on multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774024/intellij-working-on-multiple-projects)

Comment: @CrazyCoder the link you mentioned didn't solve my issue. I've 3 indepedent Eclipse projects based on mavan. First project is framework whose class I would like to use in other 2 projects.  But as per link above added Module Dependencies, didn't solve my issue. Dependent project can't class from framework project.  In Eclipse I just add dependent project under "Java Build Path" & it does the magic. please clarify what may be wrong in IDEA ?

Comment: @EngineerDollery I did look at the link you provided before posting this query. But it didn't solve my problem. Can you please check explanation given above ?

Comment: You have the answer with the working sample in the forum. What else do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get it working be referring to below links

Main link to refer to

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add_dependency

Other helpful links to understand concepts in IDEA for those coming from Eclipse world

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/about-projects.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/about-modules.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/working-with-module-dependencies.html
- https://github.com/jamesward/maven-multi-module-example
- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000448990-How-to-combine-3-maven-projects-into-single-window?page=1#community_comment_115000360310