# Combine two java projects in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two separate projects (project1, project2) with a different database. Now I want to combine both projects with new project name (project). how can I combine using eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to simply copy their contents into a new project, either with two different source directories (e.g. `cp -R Project1/src Project/src1`, `cp -R Project2/src Project/src2`) or even just merging the file contents into the same directory, if you literally want to combine them.

Better, however, would be to have Project [*reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090829/how-to-reference-a-different-java-project-in-eclipse) the existing two projects, you can keep developing Project1 and Project2 and Project will just reference the code in those projects.

Comment: In my project1 and project2 each project having two packages (pack1, pack2). In my New project (project) I want to create two packages(pack3,pack4) then I want to implement the two projects into the packages(pack3->project1,pack4->project2) is it possible.

Comment: Renaming the packages (also called refactoring) can be done separately from copying to a new project.  Copy the source code to your new project as described, then right click on the packages and select `Refactor > Rename`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to Create a  New Common Database for your projects.
2. Run both the projects in ecllipse individually.
3. Copy the Contents of any one project into another.

Answer (score 0):

To combine projects,

- Need to have same build tool.
- Have both code under the same src with different packages.
- Regarding both Databases,

  - Can have both databases using two different drivers or ORM etc.
  - If there is common data, can use two different databases. But, join the data using data structures.
- Or Can have common database.