# Extract .jar with dependencies in eclipse to use in an Android Studio project

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, libs

So I have a project made in eclipse which has 2 main folders src, where I have 2 packages with different classes, and lib, where I have some external jars that I use in my own classes.

Now I should extract this project into a .jar file so I can include it as an external library in another project. So I should be able to use the classes of the first project in the new one, such as import jarName.class1;

I've been looking on the internet but couldn't find a solution for an eclipse project with dependencies. Hope someone can inspire me.

Thanks!

edit: note that I want to open the second project in Android Studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference a different Java project in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090829/how-to-reference-a-different-java-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: no, it's not. That doesn't work for Android Studio.

Comment: you should edit your title then

Comment: you should read the body of the message before answering then, because it's explained there. I will change the title anyways.

Comment: do you mean `extract this project into a .jar` or `ARCHIVE this project into a .jar` ?

Comment: mm I don't know the correct expression for what I want to do. I just want to call my classes from another project. Every time I import the .jar I make to Android Studio it shows an error (which is because I didn't create the .jar properly).

Comment: what error do you get? how does your jar look?